# regular expression replace: count the "one or more" occurrences amount

Tags: ruby, regex

I have a regex:

```
/([^\r])(\n)+/
```

and I want it to be replaced with:

```
"#{$1}#{replacement_var}"
```

when `$2` has to be the exact number of `"\n"`s that come after a non `"\r"` character.

For instance: if `replacement_var = "ben"`, then:

```
"0\n\r\n\n123\n\n\n456\r\n"
```

should become:

```
"0ben\r\nben123benbenben456\r\n"
```

I can do a trick of giving up the `([^\r])` in the regex and then replace again ("\rben" with "\r\n"), but I wonder if I can avoid two regex operations and do it in one.

Comment: Please read "[mcve]". We'd like to see the minimal code you wrote toward solving this. Currently you've given us requirements only, which sounds like you want us to write it for you. It's not good practice to rely on `$1` and `$2` captures. They're globals and will get stomped on. Look at named captures in the regex documentation instead.

Answer (score 2):

Try something like

```
replacement_var = "ben"
"0\n\r\n\n123\n\n\n456\r\n".gsub(/((?<!\r)\n+)/) { replacement_var * $1.size } 
#=> "0ben\r\nben123benbenben456\r\n"
```

Comment: You beat me to it :) I had something quite similar, but I wasted too much time overthinking what you so elegantly achieved with `$1.size`. Very nice!

Comment: For the record, this was what I finally ended up with, essentially yours but with a named capture group: `s.gsub(/(?<newlines>(?<!\r)\n+)/) { replacement_var * $~[:newlines].size }`